Local Costmap is not receiving map in "Odom global frame" while using AMCL and GMapping in SLAM
I am implementing SLAM using the AMCL (Adaptive Monte Carlo Localization) and GMapping packages in ROS. While the map is successfully displayed on the Global Costmap, it does not appear on the Local Costmap. I have double-checked my configurations and launch files but haven't been able to resolve this issue.
Setup:

I am using a single parameters file for all navigation nodes and use
single launch file to launch the nodes.

Problem:

The map is correctly displayed on the Global Costmap.
The map does not appear on the Local Costmap.
When Odom is used as a global frame then the local cost map do not receive the map and when map is used as a global frame the local costmap receives the map correctly.

Here are some details about my setup:
ROS Version: ROS-Humble
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
GMapping Launch Files:
use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='false')
rviz_dir = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('megabot'), 'rviz', 'mws.rviz')

param_substitutions = {
    'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
    'scan_topic': 'scan',
    'base_frame': 'base_link',
    'odom_frame': 'odom',
    'map_frame': 'map',
    'map_update_interval': 3.0,
    'maxUrange': 10.0,
    'sigma': 0.05,
    'kernelSize': 1,
    'lstep': 0.05,
    'astep': 0.05,
    'iterations': 5,
    'lsigma': 0.075,
    'ogain': 3.0,
    'lskip': 0,
    'srr': 0.1,
    'srt': 0.2,
    'str': 0.1,
    'stt': 0.2,
    'linearUpdate': 0.3,
    'angularUpdate': 3.14,
    'temporalUpdate': 5.0,
    'resampleThreshold': 0.5,
    'particles': 30,
    'xmin': -15.0,
    'ymin': -15.0,
    'xmax': 15.0,
    'ymax': 15.0,
    'delta': 0.025,
    'llsamplerange': 0.01,
    'llsamplestep': 0.01,
    'lasamplerange': 0.005,
    'lasamplestep': 0.005,
}
 
return LaunchDescription([
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        name='open_rviz',
        default_value='false',
        description='Open RViz'
    ),
    Node(
        package='slam_gmapping',
        executable='slam_gmapping',
        parameters=[param_substitutions],
        output='screen',
    ),
    Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        arguments=['-d', rviz_dir],
        parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
        condition=IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration("open_rviz")),
    ),
])

Navigation Launch File:
namespace = LaunchConfiguration('namespace')
use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
autostart = LaunchConfiguration('autostart')
params_file = LaunchConfiguration('params_file')
local_parmas=LaunchConfiguration('local_parmas')
use_composition = LaunchConfiguration('use_composition')
container_name = LaunchConfiguration('container_name')
use_respawn = LaunchConfiguration('use_respawn')
# map_subscribe_transient_local = LaunchConfiguration('map_subscribe_transient_local')

lifecycle_nodes = ['controller_server',
                   'smoother_server',
                   'planner_server',
                   'behavior_server',
                   'bt_navigator',
                   'waypoint_follower']


# Create our own temporary YAML files that include substitutions
param_substitutions = {
    'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
    'autostart': autostart
    # ,'map_subscribe_transient_local': map_subscribe_transient_local
    }

configured_params = RewrittenYaml(
        source_file=params_file,
        root_key=namespace,
        param_rewrites=param_substitutions,
        convert_types=True)

stdout_linebuf_envvar = SetEnvironmentVariable(
    'RCUTILS_LOGGING_BUFFERED_STREAM', '1')

declare_namespace_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'namespace',
    default_value='',
    description='Top-level namespace')

declare_use_sim_time_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'use_sim_time',
    default_value='false',
    description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true')

# declare_local_params_file_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
#     'local_parmas',
#     default_value=os.path.join(my_param_dir, local_costmap_params),
#     description='Full path to the ROS2 parameters file to use')

declare_params_file_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'params_file',
    default_value=os.path.join(my_param_dir, my_param_file),
    description='Full path to the ROS2 parameters file to use')

gzserver_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
        os.path.join(BT_ros2,'launch','bt_ros2.launch.py')
    )
)

declare_autostart_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'autostart', default_value='true',
    description='Automatically startup the nav2 stack')

declare_use_composition_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'use_composition', default_value='False',
    description='Use composed bringup if True')

declare_container_name_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'container_name', default_value='nav2_container',
    description='the name of conatiner that nodes will load in if use composition')

declare_use_respawn_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'use_respawn', default_value='False',
    description='Whether to respawn if a node crashes. Applied when composition is disabled.')

load_nodes = GroupAction(
    condition=IfCondition(PythonExpression(['not ', use_composition])),
    actions=[
        Node(
            package='nav2_controller',
            executable='controller_server',
            output='screen',
            respawn=use_respawn,
            respawn_delay=2.0,
            parameters=[configured_params],
            ),
        Node(
            package='nav2_smoother',
            executable='smoother_server',
            name='smoother_server',
            output='screen',
            respawn=use_respawn,
            respawn_delay=2.0,
            parameters=[configured_params],
            ),
        Node(
            package='nav2_planner',
            executable='planner_server',
            name='planner_server',
            output='screen',
            respawn=use_respawn,
            respawn_delay=2.0,
            parameters=[configured_params],
            ),
        Node(
            package='nav2_behaviors',
            executable='behavior_server',
            name='behavior_server',
            output='screen',
            respawn=use_respawn,
            respawn_delay=2.0,
            parameters=[configured_params],
            ),
        Node(
            package='nav2_bt_navigator',
            executable='bt_navigator',
            name='bt_navigator',
            output='screen',
            respawn=use_respawn,
            respawn_delay=2.0,
            parameters=[configured_params],
            ),
        Node(
            package='nav2_waypoint_follower',
            executable='waypoint_follower',
            name='waypoint_follower',
            output='screen',
            respawn=use_respawn,
            respawn_delay=2.0,
            parameters=[configured_params],
            ),
        Node(
            package='nav2_lifecycle_manager',
            executable='lifecycle_manager',
            name='lifecycle_manager_navigation',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time},
                        {'autostart': autostart},
                        {'node_names': lifecycle_nodes}]),
    ]
)

load_composable_nodes = LoadComposableNodes(
    condition=IfCondition(use_composition),
    target_container=container_name,
    composable_node_descriptions=[
        ComposableNode(
            package='nav2_controller',
            plugin='nav2_controller::ControllerServer',
            name='controller_server',
            parameters=[configured_params],
            ),
        ComposableNode(
            package='nav2_smoother',
            plugin='nav2_smoother::SmootherServer',
            name='smoother_server',
            parameters=[configured_params],
            ),
        ComposableNode(
            package='nav2_planner',
            plugin='nav2_planner::PlannerServer',
            name='planner_server',
            parameters=[configured_params],
            ),
        ComposableNode(
            package='nav2_behaviors',
            plugin='behavior_server::BehaviorServer',
            name='behavior_server',
            parameters=[configured_params],
            ),
        ComposableNode(
            package='nav2_bt_navigator',
            plugin='nav2_bt_navigator::BtNavigator',
            name='bt_navigator',
            parameters=[configured_params],
            ),
        ComposableNode(
            package='nav2_waypoint_follower',
            plugin='nav2_waypoint_follower::WaypointFollower',
            name='waypoint_follower',
            parameters=[configured_params],
            ),
        ComposableNode(
            package='nav2_lifecycle_manager',
            plugin='nav2_lifecycle_manager::LifecycleManager',
            name='lifecycle_manager_navigation',
            parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
                         'autostart': autostart,
                         'node_names': lifecycle_nodes}]),
    ],
)

static_transform_publisher_node = Node(
    package='tf2_ros',
    executable='static_transform_publisher',
    name='base_footprint_to_odom_broadcaster',
    arguments=['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'base_footprint', 'odom'],
    output='screen'
)

static_transform_publisher_node_map = Node(
    package='tf2_ros',
    executable='static_transform_publisher',
    name='base_footprint_to_map_broadcaster',
    arguments=['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'map', 'base_footprint'],
    output='screen'
    )       


# Create the launch description and populate
ld = LaunchDescription()

# Set environment variables
ld.add_action(stdout_linebuf_envvar)

ld.add_action(static_transform_publisher_node)

# Declare the launch options
ld.add_action(declare_namespace_cmd)
ld.add_action(declare_use_sim_time_cmd)
ld.add_action(declare_params_file_cmd)
ld.add_action(declare_autostart_cmd)
ld.add_action(declare_use_composition_cmd)
ld.add_action(declare_container_name_cmd)
ld.add_action(declare_use_respawn_cmd)
ld.add_action(static_transform_publisher_node_map)

# Add the actions to launch all of the navigation nodes
ld.add_action(load_nodes)
ld.add_action(load_composable_nodes)
# ld.add_action(gzserver_cmd)


return ld

Costmap Configuration:
Global Costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      rolling_window: false
      use_sim_time: True
      robot_radius: 0.3
      resolution: 0.05
      width: 10
      height: 10
      origin_x: -5.0
      origin_y: -5.0
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
        enabled: true
        map_topic: /map
        subscribe_to_updates: true
        map_subscribe_transient_local: False

      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

Local Costmap:
local_costmap:
ros__parameters:
  update_frequency: 1.0
  publish_frequency: 1.0
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  rolling_window: True
  use_sim_time: False
  robot_radius: 0.3
  resolution: 0.05
  width: 10
  height: 10
  origin_x: -5.0
  origin_y: -5.0
  resolution: 0.05
  track_unknown_space: true
  plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
  obstacle_layer:
    plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
    enabled: True
    observation_sources: scan
    scan:
      topic: /scan
      max_obstacle_height: 2.0
      clearing: True
      marking: True
      data_type: "LaserScan"
      raytrace_max_range: 3.0
      raytrace_min_range: 0.0
      obstacle_max_range: 2.5
      obstacle_min_range: 0.0
  static_layer:
    plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True
    enabled: true
    map_topic: /map
    subscribe_to_updates: true
    map_subscribe_transient_local: False

  inflation_layer:
    plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
    cost_scaling_factor: 1.0
    inflation_radius: 0.2
  always_send_full_costmap: True

Important links:
This link contains my complete workspace, rqt_graph,frames and problem image
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FR_AIa7PpRXGW4gT7mpCvH412VFmO0j_?usp=drive_link

No email addresses please.
